# I don't know why this method is called twice

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment

I'm making a feature that pops up an empty dialog and enters comments.

The dialog consists of a `RecyclerView`.

And items consist of `EditText`.

Only one line of comments can be entered.

Pressing `EnterKey` dynamically creates the next comment input field.

However, when i press the enter key, `two items` are created.

Using the `Toast message`, I noticed that `OnAddComment()` was called twice.

Even after debugging, I am not sure why there are two.

What's the problem?

***writing_comment_item.xml***

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/comment_edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_bullet_point"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:maxLength="22"
    android:imeOptions="actionNone"/>
```

***WritingCommentDialogFragment.java***

```
public class WritingCommentDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    List<String> items;
    WritingCommentAdapter commentAdapter;
    RecyclerView comment_rv;
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_writing_comment_dialog, container, false);

        initViews(view);
        prepareForRecyclerView();
        commentAdapter.setOnWrtingCommentListener(new WritingCommentAdapter.OnWritingCommentListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnAddComment(int pos) {
                items.add("TEST");
                commentAdapter.addItems(items, pos);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setDialogSize();
    }
    private void setDialogSize() {
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(1000, 1000);
    }

    private void initViews(View view) {
        comment_rv = view.findViewById(R.id.comment_rv);
    }

    private void prepareForRecyclerView() {
        commentAdapter = new WritingCommentAdapter();
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, true);
        comment_rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        comment_rv.setAdapter(commentAdapter);
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(null);
        commentAdapter.addItem(items);
    }
}
```

***Adapter.java***

```
public class WritingCommentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WritingCommentAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    List<String> commentItems;
    OnWritingCommentListener listener;
    Context context;

    public void setOnWrtingCommentListener(OnWritingCommentListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void addItem(List<String> items) {
        commentItems = items;
    }

    public void addItems(List<String> items, int pos) {
        commentItems = items;
        notifyItemInserted(pos);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.writing_comment_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
 
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return commentItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        EditText comment;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_edit);

            comment.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override // IME Option NONE ( ENTER KEY)
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    if(listener != null) {
                        listener.OnAddComment(getAdapterPosition());

                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        public void setItem(String str) {
            comment.setText(str);
        }
    }

    public interface OnWritingCommentListener {
        public void OnAddComment(int pos);
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the values of `actionId` and `event` for the two calls? Do they differ?

Comment: No, I didn't check it. As a result of the verification, the value of `actionId` is `0` and I don't know the `value of event`. It seems that the value is not displayed correctly.

I'll post a picture.

Comment: It is receiving callback 2 times. One for action ACTION_DOWN & one for action ACTION_UP when he is pressing the enter button.

Comment: @Kishan Maurya Oh really.

As a result of debugging, it was confirmed that the action of the event comes in twice, `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`.

But what about the solution to this?

Comment: if(listener != null) {
                    if( event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        listener.OnAddComment(getAdapterPosition());
                    }
                }

Comment: @Kishan Maurya wow, it work well! thank you. but can i ask one more?

Comment: sure, plz ask your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is receiving callback 2 times. One for action `ACTION_DOWN` & one for action `ACTION_UP` when he is pressing the enter button.

```
if(listener != null) { if( event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { listener.OnAddComment(getAdapterPosition()); } }
```

So add comments only when action is `ACTION_DOWN`.

Comment: the question you were trying to ask was solved and it's a question of your answer.

According to your answer, is the `EnterKey` on Android that the `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` actions are `one`? Please understand even if English is awkward

Comment: When you press enter key, there are 2 events happening. 
You press enter key & as soon as you lift your finger up, there is release action. So 2 events are there.

Comment: i understood well. Thank you :)